# Select command on DataRow using the like command

Tags: c#, dataset, datarow

I have a line of code that I want to return all the rows in a dataset where a column has a name like

```
var rows = data.Tables[0].Select("Name like '" + username+ "['");
```

So basically I want to return all the rows where a column called Name has a username with a `[` just after its

eg

```
John [Smith]
John [Kelly]
```

the function above should return both of these because there is a `[` just after their name

Comment: try this, `Select("Name like '" + username+ " [%'");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add '%' after '['

```
var rows = data.Tables[0].Select("Name like '" + username+ " [[]%'");
```

Comment: Thanks but I get an error - Error in Like operator: the string pattern 'John [%' is invalid.

Comment: Edited, forgot that you have to escape bracer.